# ng build --base-href="/.../" --deploy-url="/.../" css background image not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli, scss-mixins, angular8

"@angular/core": "~8.0.0",

scaffold angular 8 project with scss style option

i have code for as mentioned below in component scss file

> background: url("/assets/images/vector-icon.png") no-repeat 25%;

at the final buil using command

```
ng build --prod --base-href="/website/" --deploy-url="/website/"
```

put build at sub folder
root/webside

everything working fine except background image path

i have tried by ip/website/assets/images/vector-icon.png
at that point i am able to get image.

What if i don't wont to change the path at every css file.

any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

The solution is to put "rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls": true in the angular.json file.

The / before assets is correct.( url(/assets/img...) )

```
 "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
           ...
           "rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls": true
```

Comment: This issue arose for us when upgrading from Angular 6 to 8. Adding this in the build options, fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Reference: https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: @curiousBoy What would replace it? Because this functionality is needed, apps simply don't work without this rebasing

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `/` before assets

```
background: url("assets/images/vector-icon.png") no-repeat 25%;
```

**PS**. And the `assets/images` folder has to contain this image.

**PPS**. Make sure this path is correct.

Comment: getting this error (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:

Comment: @parasshah does your `assets/images` folder contain this `vector-icon.png` file actually at the time of building?

Comment: @parasshah I asked, because you have to see this error, in case an image doesn't exist or a path is incorrect.

Comment: @Don_Toamto yes you are right at same path image is exists and it is working at loca host

Comment: but how can i overcome the compilation error due to whic i am not able to build my project

Comment: @parasshah Building should work as well as local serve, subject to the availability of image you reference to in styles.

Comment: i agree but it isn't working in my case i do have image at correct path and also did the same as you said but getting this error of compilation can you please help me that ?

 (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:

Comment: @parasshah could you create a new empty angular project and reproduce this error. And upload it to the GitHub?

Comment: Having the same issue. Base path set and working for everything except the background image. Seems to be limited to Angular 8, as its fine in my Angular 7 project

Answer (score 1):

Faced this problem myself. Instead of `/assets...`, use `src/assets...`. Make sure you don't put `/` before `src`.

Comment: This add a copy of your image  in your root of dist folder,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background: url("/src/assets/images/vector-icon.png") no-repeat 25%;
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing you need to check that go to assets folder and check that file exists or not. If file exists, try below line

```
background: url('./assets/images/vector-icon.png') no-repeat 25%;
```

Comment: getting same compilation error 
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: