# How to use --deploy-url + css background url properly

Tags: css, angular

I am building my angular app with `ng build --deploy-url="/foo/bar/"` and trying to display background images using css `background: url("url");`, but in the browser's dev tool I see incorrect url when it is trying to get the image.

if I try with:
`background: url("assets/img/img.svg")` or `background: url("./assets/img/img.svg")`
the request in the browser looks like:
http://localhost:38080/foo/bar/img.svg
So `/assets/img/` disapears.

if I try with:
`background: url("/assets/img/img.svg")`
the request in the browser looks like:
http://localhost:38080/assets/img/img.svg
Which is kind of expected, but who knows I tried..

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625979/ng-build-base-href-deploy-url-css-background-image-not-worki

Answer (score 0):

give the url **without quote** it will take care and resolve.

```
background: url(./assets/img/img.svg)
```

in my project i do it like at top of scss file

```
  $svg-relative-part: "./../../../../assets/svg/";
  $grey-close: 'grey.svg';
  background: url($svg-relative-part + $grey);
```